# Поместить лямбду в список

Tags: python, функции, lambda

Написал функцию которая получает параметр температуры (число, по умолчанию 30),и в зависимости от величины информирует, холодно сегодня, или жарко (больше 25 - жарко, иначе холодно).  И, необходимо создать список, в который поместить лямбда-функцию, которая будет исполнять тот же функционал, что и функция is_hot_today.
С лямбдами не сладко. И функциями тоже :) Поделитесь пожалуйста своими комментариями и мнением верно ли написан код, и почему ?

```
def is_hot_today(temprature = 30):
        if temprature >= 25:
            result = 'The weater is hot today!'
            return result
        if temprature < 25:
            result = 'The weather is cold today!'
            return result
    
    
    my_list = [lambda temp:temp > 25 or temp < 25]
```

Comment: Вам список для чего? Чтобы помещать туда результаты работы функции через определенные промежутки времени?

Comment: Тернарный оператор вас однозначно тут спасёт, всё очень просто будет, когда разберётесь.

Comment: @MarchelloA Да, но без промежутков времени.

Answer (score 2):

- `if`/`if` -> `if`/`else`. Это не ошибка, это недочёт.
- Лямбда возвращает булево значение, а должна текстовое сообщение. Почитайте про [условное выражение](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=ternary#conditional-expressions).
- Условие в лямбде странное. Хотя её всю надо будет переписать.

Comment: Проясните пожалуйста, в чем его странность ?

Comment: `temp > 25 or temp < 25` означает то же самое что и `temp != 25`, только записано многословно. Странно.